# Find DataFrame entries where certain columns are all NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am constructing a dataframe that contains daily information. I want to one-hot encode the days for a machine learning algorithm, however I am not sure how to find the entires that contain NaN for each day and set that day to True for all its entries. Then at the end, set all remaining NaN values to False.

```
print("Starting to process files...")
#Init dataframe
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=["start", "close", "state", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"])
#Define days
weekdays = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
#Then for each day of the week, creep through all the files and append entries to dataframe
for day in weekdays:
    files = getFilesFromDir("datastream/"+day+"/")
    print("Processing " + day)
    for file in files:
        print("Processing...")
        content = readCSV(file)
        df = transformData(df, content)
        print("File finished.")
        print(df.size)
        break
    #Done with this day, assign one-hot encoded value to its column and proceed to next day
    df[day] = True
```

The problem with this current solution is that once tuesday is done, all of the monday entries will also be assigned True for tuesday, etc. This is why I am asking how to only find entries that have NaN in each of the 7 days so I can set only those entries to True. Then at the very end set all remaining NaN to false.

transformData() is a long method but thats where the entries are written into the dataframe but it would not be too practical to also assign these values in there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to decipher your aim from the posted code, but unless there's a really good reason to do this process while you're loading the files, just do it one time once the files are loaded. From your code it doesn't look like there are any memory advantages to doing the processing on the fly.

This is what I've used previously to one hot encode date times in a dataframe based upon weekday;

```py
df['weekday_name'] = df['my_datetime_column'].dt.strftime('%A')
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['weekday_name'])], axis=1).drop(['weekday_name', 'index'], axis=1)
```

Comment: I have a lot (a LOT!) of data rows (around 18k rows per file, and about 20 files for each day) so I don't want to have to attach extra string labels to the data set to then transform to one-hot encoding (hence why I hadn't posted a snippet of the dataframe, its hard to understand it by just a fragment)

Comment: Hi @peterxz, I typically do this on dataframes with 1m+ rows, so 360k rows should be no trouble.

Comment: You can probably do this without the intermediate step - ```df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.my_datetime_column.dt.strftime("%A"))], axis=1), axis=1)```, the additional step was more for clarity. Give it a go and see if it falls over before optimising :)